# Excel: Search data table and check for multiple values and place "X" if True/found

Tags: excel

Ok, so I have not found a thread that solves my question.
I have an Excel workbook with a data table of a few hundred classes and their "category" next to them. On another sheet, I have copied the classes over and removed duplicates. I am trying to find a good way to search through the first sheet for that class and category. Some classes have 2 different categories. So I need a formula to search through the classes and place an "X" where it is true.
[image]

[image]

Notice that the first picture at ANT 2010 has 2 categories.
The function that I need to input go into the 2nd pictures Lit,NL,SS... cells. I have gotten it to input an X on the first instance but I cannot get the second instance to work.

Please help me or guide me to a more proper thread.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNITFS:

This assumes your second table starts in A1 and your first list is on a sheet named `Data`.

Put in B2 copy over and down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Data!$J:$J,$A2,Data!$K:$K,B$1),"X","")
```

[image]

Comment: @tbreck11 Works for me.  make sure the references are correct.

Comment: I don't know what I did but it works now, you are wonderful! Thank you seriously!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pivot Table on your original data.

- Drag Course to the Rows area
- Drag Category to both the Columns and Values areas
- Ensure Value Field Settings = Count

  - Set a custom number format of `"X";;;`
- Apply desired formatting

[image]

You can also use `Get & Transform` or `Power Query` if you have Excel 2010 or later. Let me know if you prefer that.